# GPX file validation

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to make sure that an uploaded file is a valid gpx file and tried two different checks (for xml) as GPX is xml (kind of).

The first check rejects a valid file with the message no DTD found.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->Load($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"]);
if ($dom->validate()) {

}
else {
    echo '<script>alert("Not a valid GPS file!");</script>';            
    exit();
}
```

The second check does NOT reject invalid files like jpg or pdf.

```
$xmlcontents = XMLReader::open($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"]);

$xmlcontents->setParserProperty(XMLReader::VALIDATE, true);

if($xmlcontents->isValid()) {
}
else {
    echo '<script>alert("Not a valid GPS file!");</script>';            
    exit();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Maybe you could use this: http://www.topografix.com/gpx_validation.asp

Comment: valid xml is not the same thing as well formed. "valid" xml simply means the document meets the XML requirements. It says nothing about the CONTENTS of the xml. well formed means it's valid XML **AND** meets the requirements of a particular DTD. `<foo><bar /></foo>` is valid xml, but if you validate that against (say) the X-HTML DTD, it won't be well-formed.

Comment: @LajosVeres Thanks but I can not install anything on my webspace.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks! What I simply want to do is to check whether the file is "true" XML and not something fishy. Besides of the extension check of course.

Comment: `->isValid()` only checks for xml validity. `->validate()` expects a DTD to check for well-formedness, and your system must not have the GPX dtd available to check against.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks again! But why does ->isValid() not reject files like jpg?

Comment: not sure. maybe it's being interpreted as one solid long text node for lack of `<? ... ?>` tag pairs?

Comment: @MarcB So what should I than do? :)

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution!

```
 $xml=simplexml_load_file($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"]);
if($xml ===  FALSE)
{
    echo '<script>alert("Not a valid GPS file!");</script>';            
    exit();
}
```

This returns false for jpg, pdf and so on but accepts GPX.